# celery doesn't run simple print

Tags: django, celery

I have a helloworld type function for celery:

```
from celery import Celery
import time
app = Celery('test_celery',
             broker= 'amqp://celeryuser:pass@ip:5672/celeryvhost',
             )

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(2)
    print('calculating something aaewsome --------------------')
    return x + y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = add.delay(4, 4)
    print( result.get() )
```

I run the command to run the task:

```
celery -A test_celery worker --loglevel=info
```

I get the output:

```
[tasks]
  . test_celery.add
[2018-07-17 00:17:40,668: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://celeryuser:**@myip:5672/celeryvhost
[2018-07-17 00:17:40,679: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-07-17 00:17:41,705: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: sync with 1 nodes
[2018-07-17 00:17:41,706: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: sync complete
[2018-07-17 00:17:41,725: INFO/MainProcess] celery@www.mysite.com ready.
```

In the logs it shows:

```
[2018-07-17 00:17:40,698: INFO/MainProcess] sync with celery@mysite.com
```

But no output prints.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the celery task anywhere, that's why it's not printing.
**Step.1** Open your terminal and run the command,
 `celery -A test_celery worker --loglevel=info`
**Step.2** Open another terminal and import the celery task, then run it with `.delay()`

**Screenshots**
1. Celery command running 
[image: Celery command]
2. Calling celery task
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the app with a result backend passed as an argument. Example

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='pyamqp://')
```